# Get a list-element using Jquery on IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I signed up here because i have one problem using JQuery on Internet Explorer. I have a button, which generates a pdf-file of my html code, and for the name of this pdf, I try to get the name of the page where the user is. All the names of the pages are stored in "li" elements, and Bootstrap changes theses "li" class in active when the user is in. For example, i have :

```
<ul>
   <li class="active"><a>Tar </a></li>
   <li> <a>ER</a> </li>
<ul>
```

So when the user clicks on ER, its li class becomes active, and the li class of Tar becomes nothing. To get the content of these li, I use JQuery with

```
 $('li.active a').html();
```

But, when I click on ER, the value will be Tar, and when I'll click on Tar again, I will have ER as value. What can I do to have the good value without delay? Thanks to anyone who will help me!

Ps: Excuse me for my bad english :)

Comment: What does the `.click()` method look like?

Comment: For now this is juste a console.log of the value.

Comment: So you should put your code to get the current element's HTML into the `.click` method like `$(this).html()`

Comment: It helps to get the name, and thanks, but I didn't notice (and sorry for that) that I have one Button (in every page)to launch the action for the pdf, and with $(this).html() I get, as a name for the pdf, the name of the image of my button.

Comment: You have a button... that's what you already told us. But you also said that you clicked on `Tar` or `ER` rather than the button. And we would like to see that `.click()` method (not the one of the button)

Comment: So I didn't explain myself as I wanted, and I apologize. The .click() for the list elements initializes the html of these elements if they never have been clicked before. In this html, i have one button which generates the pdf, and on the .click() of the pdf-button, I need to get the name of the list-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `.active` class, which is triggered after the user clicks, you should use the click event itself - it contains a reference of the item that got clicked ( the `<a>` element in your case ) which can be used directly.

Try this :

```
$(this).html();
```

and it should work for you.

Also, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udSsc/1/) with a simple example.

**Edit:** here's a [second Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fMLm/) with a button to do the triggering (via a custom class on click of `<a>`)

Comment: It helps to get the name, and thanks, but I didn't notice (and sorry for that) that I have one Button (in every page)to launch the action for the pdf, and with $(this).html() I get, as a name for the pdf, the name of the image of my button.

Comment: I Think I can get the $(this).html() value in a global variable and I can access this one in another javascript page, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: please provide a clearer explanation - if the user clicks on a button, how does **he** select the appropriate `<li>`?

Comment: He can click on every <li>  which appeared at the top of all pages, and in these pages, there is a button which generates the pdf. For each page, the  <li> becomes class="active", and if the user clicks on another <li>  , this one will be active, and the other page, with another content and another pdf-button, will appeared

Comment: so the page is reloaded after clicking `<a>`? Does the `<a>` have an `href` attribute? If not, it might be easier to have a custom click handler for the `<a>` tags that adds/removes your own `active`-like class.

Comment: nope, the page isn't reloaded, and the <a> have href, on a javascript function which, with a switch, checks if the page have already loaded or not

Comment: added second fiddle that tracks clicked `<a>` via custom class, and a button.